# NSSortDescriptor on to many relationship subatributes sum

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

At first, here is my data structure (simplified) :

```
CATEGORY
    -name
    -subcategories  <- this is a to many relationship to SUBCATEGORY

SUBCATEGORY
    -name
    -elements <- this is a to many relation to ELEMENT

ELEMENT
    -name
```

I want to fetch my CATEGORY objects using a `NSSortDescriptor` to order them on the sum of their subcategories elements count.

Example :
CATEGORY (A) has three SUBCATEGORY (A1, A2, A3)
A1 has 3 elements, A2 has 2 elements, A3 has 3 elements
That make 3 + 2 + 3 = 8

CATEGORY (B) has two SUBCATEGORY (B1, B2)
B1 has 2 elements, B2 has 11 elements
That make 2 + 11 = 13

So B should be before A

My question is :
Is it possible to perform this without creating an attribute that is just counting the number of elements in each category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* of course use a separate attribute which you can update automatically by certain triggers that you can configure by implementing overrides in your managed object subclasses, e.g. `willSave` or `setSubcategory`.

Fortunately, this is not necessary because sort descriptors support keypaths.

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"subcategories.@count", ascending:YES];
```

You need to first fetch all object and then apply the sort in memory with this setup. If this is not feasible you will have to go with the first solution.

Comment: That's what I relinquished to do, so I'll accept this answer but I wish I could do this without loading data in memory, then count everything...